# How can I install the Phalcon Devtools

Tags: php, phalcon

For the version 0.5.0 of Phalcon, how can I install the phalcon-devtools so that I can use them through the command shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although at the time of this writing Phalcon-Devtools for 0.5.0 is still in alpha stage, they are stable enough to be used in development environments.

Phalcon Devtools are now offered via a PEAR channel.

Instructions (also available in http://pear.phalconphp.com)

**Registering the channel**

```
pear channel-discover pear.phalconphp.com
```

**Listing available packages**

```
pear remote-list -c phalcon
```

**Installing a package**

```
pear install phalcon/package_name
```

**Installing a specific version/stability**

```
pear install phalcon/package_name-1.0.0
pear install phalcon/package_name-beta
```

You can also receive updates using the channel's [feed](http://pear.phalconphp.com/feed.xml)

As of 2012-09-09 the commands are:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phalconphp.com
pear install phalcon/Devtools-0.5.0
```

If everything went well, issue:

```
phalcon commands
```

and you will see:

```
Phalcon DevTools (0.5.0a4)

Available commands:
  commands
  controller
  model
  project
  scaffold
```